# How can I send property from BroadcastReceiver1 to BroadcastReceiver2?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

I have one service and two `BroadcastReceiver`. I am calling first receiver like:

```
private static final String CALLACTION = "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE";

final IntentFilter theCallFilter = new IntentFilter();
theCallFilter.addAction(CALLACTION);

yourCallReceiver = new CallReceiver();        
registerReceiver(yourCallReceiver, theCallFilter);
```

and the second one similar like first one.

Now I need to set data from one receiver to another. I want to set `Boolean` property which will check if the code in first `BroadcastReceiver` is done something and if is it then code in second can be executed. How can i send this property from "BroadcastReceiver1" to "BroadcastReceiver2" ?

Comment: sending the same intent with an extra from the receiver?

Comment: sending property value from one receiver to another... do you have any examplmaybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply using a BroadcastRecevier, you can't be sure the order the system will resolve them in. The answer here is to use ordered Broadcast instead. You can then set the result and check that result in your next receiver.
Here is a great post from the Google Blog http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/01/processing-ordered-broadcasts.html

Comment: that way i am thinking how to create some kind of static class that both receiver can use it

Comment: alright. Well you don't want to take my suggestion then. You can extend Application and use that as your global static class.

Comment: your ideas is good but i don't know how to implement it right now that way i remeber on static class. Which you suggest?

Comment: I gave you a link with example homie. I don't know what else you are looking for.

Comment: hmm you gave me link for Non-ordered vs. Ordered Broadcasts. Maybe i am not looking correctly.